# What is the difference of 'exec cmd &' and 'cmd &' in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

What is the difference between the following fork statements ?

1. `command &`
2. `exec command &`

You can use `wait $!` for both statements.
In my test I have found no difference in the behavior - but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` overrides the `exec` since you can't *both* replace the existing process with a new process *and* run the new process in the background.

Comment: Have you a link to the relevant documentation ?

Comment: I don't know of any relevant documentation.

Comment: Perhaps it is more accurate to say that since `&` runs the command it terminates in a subshell, the `exec` replaces the subshell's process (not the calling process) with `command`.